# How can I append data to a PostgreSQL table with `dplyr` without `collect()`?

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, rpostgresql

The table `reg_data` is a PostgreSQL table. It turns out to be faster to run the regressions in PostgreSQL. But, as I am running it for 100,000s of data sets, I want to do it data set by data set and append the results of each to a table.

Is there a way to append PostgreSQL data to a PostgreSQL table using native `dplyr` verbs? I'm not sure that there's a huge cost to bringing the data to R then sending them back to PostgreSQL (it's just 6 numbers and a couple of identifying fields), but it does seem inelegant.

```
library(dplyr)

pg <- src_postgres()

reg_data <- tbl(pg, "reg_data")

reg_results <-
    reg_data %>%
    summarize(r_squared=regr_r2(y, x),
              num_obs=regr_count(y, x),
              constant=regr_intercept(y, x),
              slope=regr_slope(y, x),
              mean_analyst_fog=regr_avgx(y, x),
              mean_manager_fog=regr_avgy(y, x)) %>%
    collect() %>%
    as.data.frame()

# Push to database.
dbWriteTable(pg$con, c("bgt", "within_call_data"), reg_results,
             append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr` does not include commands to insert or update records in a database, so there is not a complete native `dplyr` solution for this. But you could combine dplyr with regular SQL statements to avoid bringing the data to R.

Let's start by reproducing your steps before the `collect()` statement

```
library(dplyr)

pg <- src_postgres()

reg_data <- tbl(pg, "reg_data")

reg_results <-
    reg_data %>%
    summarize(r_squared=regr_r2(y, x),
              num_obs=regr_count(y, x),
              constant=regr_intercept(y, x),
              slope=regr_slope(y, x),
              mean_analyst_fog=regr_avgx(y, x),
              mean_manager_fog=regr_avgy(y, x))
```

Now, you could use `compute()` instead of `collect()` to create a temporary table in the database.

```
temp.table.name <- paste0(sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")

reg_results <- reg_results %>% compute(name=temp.table.name)
```

Where `temp.table.name` is a random table name. Using the option `name = temp.table.name` in compute we assign this random name to the temporary table created.

Now, we will use the library `RPostgreSQL` to create an insert query that uses the results stored in the temporary table. As the temporary table only lives in the connection created by `src_postgresql()` we need to reuse it.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
copyconn <- pg$con
class(copyconn) <- "PostgreSQLConnection" # I get an error if I don't fix the class
```

Finally the insert query

```
sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO destination_table SELECT * FROM ", temp.tbl.name,";")

dbSendQuery(copyconn, sql)
```

So, everything is happening in the database and the data is not brought into R.

**EDIT**

Previous versions of this post did break encapsulation when we obtained `temp.tbl.name` from `reg_results`. This is avoided using the option `name=`in compute.

Answer (score 3):

another option would be to use a command called `sql_render()` to create each SQL statement, and then another command called `db_save_query()` to create the table using a SQL statement and then a manual statement to append to the table.  To loop through each query, the `purrr` commands: `map` and `walk` are used. Preferably, a command like `compute()` command should do this, but in lieu of that, the following is a fully reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(purrr)

# Setting up a SQLite db with 3 tables
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, filter(mtcars, cyl == 4), "mtcars1")
copy_to(con, filter(mtcars, cyl == 6), "mtcars2")
copy_to(con, filter(mtcars, cyl == 8), "mtcars3")



# Pre-process the SQL statements
tables <- c("mtcars1","mtcars2","mtcars3")
all_results <- tables %>%
  map(~{
    tbl(con, .x) %>%
      summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg),
                records = n()) %>%
      sql_render() 
  })

# Execute the SQL statements, 1st one creates the table
# subsquent queries are insterted to the table
first_query <- TRUE
all_results %>%
  walk(~{
    if(first_query == TRUE){
      first_query <<- FALSE
      db_save_query(con, ., "results")
    } else {
      dbExecute(con, build_sql("INSERT INTO results ", .))
    }
  })


tbl(con, "results")

dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: It would be nice if `dbWriteTable(pg, "results", ., append = TRUE)` when `.` represents a server-side table or query, simply called either `db_save_query(con, ., "results")` or `dbExecute(con, build_sql("INSERT INTO results ", .))` as applicable.

I can see work flows evolving like this:

`df %>% collect() %>% some_processing() %>% dbWriteTable()`
to this

`df %>%  some_processing() %>% collect() %>% dbWriteTable()`
where it would be nice to omit the `collect()` in the final version.